# Node JS + Express: Error object not caught on Promise reject

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

In my Express web app, I have defined a function that returns a Promise object.

```
login: function(un, pass) {
        result = {};
        var loginOk = new Promise(
            function (resolve, reject) {
                if (result.hasOwnProperty('sessionToken')) {
                    var user = {username: result["username"], sessionToken: result["sessionToken"]};
                    resolve(user); // fulfilled
                } else {
                    var reason = new Error('login failed');
                    console.log("LOGIN FAILED:" + reason.message);
                    reject(reason); // reject
                }

            }
        );
        return loginOk;
}
```

In the route that calls the login function:

```
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    const unm = req.query.username;
    const pwd = req.query.password;

    db_user.login(unm, pwd)
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("/login:" + JSON.stringify(result));
        res.send(result);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // Login failed
        console.log(error);  // This printed out {"Error":{}}
        console.log(error.message); // This printed out undefined. but supposed to be "login failed"!!!
        res.send(error.message);
    });
});
```

I would like to return the error message generated from the reject callback function to the user front-end view. The problem is the error was always empty and error.message was undefined. The catch does not seem to get the error passed over from the reject.

Comment: can you `console.log(error)` instead to see what that is - by the way, you know your `login` function will always reject, right?

Comment: Yes, I have tested some failed password to trigger the reject. "console.log("LOGIN FAILED:" + reason.message);" actually printed out what I wanted.

Comment: I added console.log(error) in the catch function. And it printed out {"Error":{}} when I triggered the route with a fake password to minic a failed login.

Comment: can you confirm that the `catch` is being executed at all?

Comment: `in the catch function printed out nothing` - yet you've added `This printed out {"Error":{}}` - so ... it's not nothing, right

Comment: can you try - `reject('login failed')`? instead of `reject(new Error('login failed'))`

Comment: Yes, after I changed to `reject('login failed')`, it printed out `{"Error":"login failed"}`. This is really weird.

Answer (score 0):

In ExpressJs, async function is not supported.
`.catch(err=>{....somecode})`.

You should use a middleware like `express-promise-router` or use `try{}catch(e){}` to catch error.